Data does not render (using react useState) after selecting a choice from a dropdown
I'm trying to get something simple to work before moving onto more complexity. In the following code I am trying to provide a simple choice of three MongoDB collections, fetch the data and then render it on my page. I can select a choice just fine but the data doesn't render. However, if I remove the code for the dropdown and hardcode a choice, it works. Is there some fundamental aspect of state and useEffect that I'm unaware of? I've pasted my code below:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const Collections = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [selectedCollection, setSelectedCollection] = useState(null) 
  const collectionList = ["participants", "kits", "visits"]

  const handleSelectedCollection = async (collection) => {
    setSelectedCollection(collection)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCollection = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/xpredict/${selectedCollection}`)
      const json = await response.json()

      if (response.ok) {
        setData(json)
      }
    }
    fetchCollection()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="participants-details">
      <h2>selection</h2>

      {<select onChange={(e) => handleSelectedCollection(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="">Select a collection</option>
        {collectionList.map((collection, index) => (
          <option key={index} value={collection}>{collection}</option>
        ))}
      </select>}
      <div>
        {data && data.map((p) => (
          <p key={p._id}>{p._id}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Collections


The data isn't fetched in response to a choice being selected, rather it just fetches data when the component mounts.
Update the logic to include the selectedCollection as a useEffect hook dependency and conditionally fetch the data when appropriate.
Example:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const collectionList = ["participants", "kits", "visits"];

const Collections = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCollection, setSelectedCollection] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCollection = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/xpredict/${selectedCollection}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle/ignore any thrown errors/rejections/etc
      }
    }

    if (selectedCollection) {
      fetchCollection();
    }
  }, [selectedCollection]);

  return (
    <div className="participants-details">
      <h2>selection</h2>

      <select onChange={(e) => setSelectedCollection(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="">Select a collection</option>
        {collectionList.map((collection) => (
          <option key={collection} value={collection}>
            {collection}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <div>
        {data.map((p) => (
          <p key={p._id}>{p._id}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Collections;

This may be a bit of an anti-pattern if you don't need to call fetchCollection elsewhere, it would be more correct and simpler to call fetchCollection directly in response to the UI event.
Example:
import { useState } from "react";

const collectionList = ["participants", "kits", "visits"];

const Collections = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  const fetchCollection = async (e) => {
    const collection = e.target.value;
    if (!collection) return;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/xpredict/${collection}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
    } catch(error) {
      // handle/ignore any thrown errors/rejections/etc
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="participants-details">
      <h2>selection</h2>

      <select onChange={fetchCollection}>
        <option value="">Select a collection</option>
        {collectionList.map((collection) => (
          <option key={collection} value={collection}>
            {collection}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <div>
        {data.map((p) => (
          <p key={p._id}>{p._id}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Collections;


That makes perfect sense and works beautifully. Thanks, Drew!
